# invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error in the title. It's pointing to the line where the for-loop is declared. Any ideas on what is happening?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T max(T* arr, size_t n)
{
    if (!n)
        throw("Can't take the max of an empty array, bro.");
    T top = arr[0];
    for (T* i(arr+1), j(arr+n); i != j; ++i)
        if (*i > top)
            top = *i;
    return top;

}

int main()
{

    char S[] = "kjadkjhdjasjkdaskjdsahd";
    std::cout << max(S, strlen(S));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this can be replaced with `std::max_element` (and is better with `std::string`), and you're missing a header for `strlen`.

Comment: That's no fun, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the line:

```
for (T* i(arr+1), j(arr+n); i != j; ++i)
```

Only the i is declared as pointer to T, j is declared as an instance of T. The correct declaration is:

```
for (T* i(arr+1),* j(arr+n); i != j; ++i)
```

And by the way, you should add include for strlen:

```
#include <cstring>
```

Comment: I've always hated how pointer declarations work in C/C++ in this regard. In my mind, the `*` goes with the type, not the variable name, and I *wish* that, e.g., `char* i,j;` meant `i` and `j` are two variables of type `char *`. I don't know if this is just an unfortunate relic of the original C language, or if it's something that's been kept for good reasons that are just beyond me. But either way, it doesn't look like it's going to change any time soon.

Comment: @MikeHolt The asterisk in declaration is bond to the variable, not the type. You're right, it has been that way since the times of C language and the C++ standards committee is very strict about maintaining backward compatibility, so I'm afraid that it will stay that way until the Armageddon.
In my opinion, it is not so important - any good book will mention this feature of C/C++ declaration grammar and there are many other things that are much more annoying...

Comment: Yes, I know that's how it is, I was merely lamenting that fact, not suggesting that the asterisk is actually bound to the type.

Answer (score 1):

That's a common error with multiple comma separated pointer variable declarations. Change your for loop header as follows:

```
for (T *i(arr+1), *j(arr+n); i != j; ++i) {
               // ^ Note the additional asterisk!
}
```

See the fixed and working [sample here](http://ideone.com/XzNTdd).